# what is the difference between MongoClient and MongoConnection

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah, scala-2.11

i want to know what is the difference between `mongoClient` and `mongoConnection` and what is the difference between these two codes

```
  serverAddress=new ServerAddress("Localhost",27017)
           client= MongoClient(serverAddress)
           testDB = client("testdb")//get database Name
           collection = testDB("mycol")//get collection Name
```

and

```
 serverAddress=new ServerAddress("Localhost",27017)
           con= MongoClient(serverAddress)
           testDB = con("testdb")//get database Name
           myCollection = testDB("mycol")//get collection Name
```

please explain what is the difference

Comment: There are no differences. Only "client" variable changes to "con" variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoConnection has been deprecated in favor of MongoClient.  To my knowledge there was no difference at the time MongoClient was introduced.  I guess the functionality may diverge over time.

From the API tutorial: [Casbah API tutorial](http://api.mongodb.org/scala/casbah/2.5.0/tutorial.html)

> "MongoClient was added to the Java driver in 2.10 as the default
>   connection class for MongoDB. Older Casbah code may use
>   MongoConnection which should be updated to use MongoClient."